# Input from UITextField connected from storyboard to Swift view controller file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Using Swift, how do I get the input from a `UITextField`?

In my Main.storyboard, I have chosen a "Text Field" from the premade components and dragged it onto my storyboard.

Now how can I access its value in my ViewController.swift?

**What I'm currently doing:**

I ctrl+drag the text field into my ViewController.swift file. Then in the popup-box I choose "outlet" and name it "myInput".

Then in another function, I access its value by using `self.myInput.text`.

Is this the only way to access its input? Is my approach following Swift conventions?

Comment: Yes, or even just myInput.text

Comment: What is the difference between using self.myInput.text, and myInput.text?

Comment: The difference is that if you have a function with a parameter or variable named myInput, you can use self.myInput to reference the property and myInput for the parameter or variable.

Comment: if you have a local variable with the same name and you need to access the class variable you use self.name. You can use self. all the time if it makes you feel good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, your approach of creating an `IBOutlet` from the storyboard and referencing it using `self.myInput.text` is a standard way of accessing this field in Swift.

As for whether to use `self.myInput` vs. `myInput`, I prefer to always write `self` because it is very obvious that the variable is a property and will probably be changed in many different places (opposed to a local var). Also, once you have `self` there, you don't have to worry about introducing local vars with the same name or making changes if you copy and paste a block of code into a closure that requires self.